# C - proper syntax for pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I call a function global var as follow:

```
char    *Pointer;
```

I then pass it into function:

```
char *MyChar = DoSomething (&Pointer);
```

which is defined as:

```
char *DoSomething (char *Destination)
{
   free (*Destination);

   //re-allocate memory
   Destination = malloc (some number);

   //then do something...       

   //finally
   return Destination;
}
```

it only works if I use (*Destination) instead of (Destination).  can someone tell me if that is correct?  I still do not understand why it does not take (Destination).

Comment: 'Destination' gives the current content of destination (which allows changing the content of the place where Destination points.)  what is actually needed is the address of 'Destination' (which allows changing the place where Destination points.)

Comment: The code should always check the returned value from malloc (and family) to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, `Destination` is already declared as a pointer, so you pass the address of `Destination` in `DoSomething(&Destination)`, that is like a pointer to pointer, then you need to dereference `Destination` inside `DoSomething()` function, for which the indirection operator `*` works.

But the right way, is not to pass the address of the pointer, but the pointer instead like in

```
DoSomething(Destination);
```

now, since you want to malloc `Destination` inside the function, you should the do this

```
char * DoSomething( char **Destination )
{
   // free( Destination ); why?

   //re-allocate memory
   *Destination = malloc( some number );

   //then do something...       

   //finally
   return *Destination;
}
```

this is a demonstration of how you can use pointers

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *copyString(const char *const source)
{
    char *result;
    int   length;

    length = strlen(source);
    result = malloc(length + 1);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    strcpy(result, source);

    printf("The address of result is : %p\n", result);
    printf("The content of result is : %s\n", result);
    printf("The first character of result is @ %p\n", &result[0]);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char *string = copyString("This is an example");

    printf("\n");

    printf("The address of string is : %p\n", string);
    printf("The content of string is : %s\n", string);
    printf("The first character of string is @ %p\n", &string[0]);

    /* we used string for the previous demonstration, now we can free it */
    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```

if you execute the previous program, you will see that the pointers both point to the same memory, and the contents of the memory are the same, so calling `free` in `main()` will realease the memory.

Comment: I want the function to do the free() operation.  that way I can keep re-using a global var.  this is related to my earlier question that you answered, and the method is how I deal with having to use free().

Comment: @CaTx You should not use malloc with global variables, and you don't need to. There is no point in doing that since the pointer always will point to the same place unless you reassign it.

Comment: @CaTx - I also agree with iharob: that `free` looks pretty smelly to me.  Since we don't see the rest of your code we can't say authoritatively to not do that, but I'd bet that's really not a good idea.

Comment: guys, I want to have the function doing the free() so I do not have to do it from the calling function.  hence, just 1 line of code at that level.  is it a good thing?  =/

Comment: @CaTx That is not possible. Use c++. Classes have destructors.

Comment: I am using a variation of C, not Visual Studio.  thus, VS C++ is not possible.

Comment: @CaTx then you have no choice. You can't make variables `free` automtically. And that kind of beats the whole benefit from allocating memory by yourself.

Comment: @CaTx even when your Idea for the global variable that will `free` itself when the function is called works, you will never be able to `free` the last `malloc`ed chunk.

Comment: @iharob, 2 things:
1. how are result/length taken care of?  they can be called multiple times.
2. looks like I have to with the long way because it's right.  I was hoping to make it look neat like C#.

Comment: That's what I meant in my comment about `having background in another programming language.` You can call `copyString` any number of times you want, and you should not worry about it's local variables, `length` is not a pointer, so it will be taken care of when `copyString` returns, and `result` will be passed to the caller, giving them the responsability of freeing it. However, if you `malloc` something inside the `copyString` function and you don't return that, you should `free` it before returning.

Comment: oh sorry, been reading around for solution. XD  so basically malloc() & et al. should not be used inside a C function?

Comment: I suppose I have to use macros instead of a function for what I want to do?

Comment: What you mean? You want to have a string, and you want that string to have dynamic size, and you don't want to `free` it manually?

Comment: I want to obtain a string resulted from multiple operations (dynamic size). coming from C#, I want to have it done with a single line of code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68520/discussion-between-iharob-and-catx).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a correct approach

```
char    *Pointer;

//,,, maybe allocating memory and assigning its address to Pointer
//... though it is not necessary because it is a global variable and
//... will be initialized by zero. So you may apply function free to the pointer.

char *MyChar = DoSomething( Pointer );


char * DoSomething( char *Destination )
{
   free( Destination );

   //re-allocate memory
   Destination = malloc( some number );

   //then do something...       

   //finally
   return Destination;
}
```

As for your code then

1. Type of the argument does not correspond to type of the parameter in function call

   char *MyChar = DoSomething (&Pointer);

the type of the parameter is `char *` ( char *Destination ) while the type of argument is
`char **` ( &Pointer )

2. As Destination is a pointer then instead of

   free (*Destination);

you have to write

```
   free( Destination );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are passing in an address of the pointer `char *Pointer` with the line

```
char *MyChar = DoSomething (&Pointer);
```

Since you are passing in the address of the pointer in your function `DoSomething` it sees the functional scope variable `Destination` as a pointer to an address that is the address of the pointer `Pointer`.

So rather than passing in the address of `Pointer` with

```
char *MyChar = DoSomething(&Pointer);
```

you need to pass in the pointer itself like so:

```
char *MyChar = DoSomething(Pointer);
```

which will allow you to use

```
free(Destination);
```

Notice the lack of `&` indicating the address of `Pointer`.